# sapui5 Error Element sap.m.Text is not valid for aggregation "_headerTitle" of Element sap.m.NotificationListItem

Tags: sapui5

We are on SAPUI5 library version 1.36.1.
We have a responsive popover to display messages to the user.
When creating & loading the Popover to the view we are getting the below message.

> Element sap.m.Text is not valid for aggregation "_headerTitle" of
>   Element sap.m.NotificationListItem

I couldn't find what's the reason as when I try it in WEB-IDE I could see it in layout editor working fine, checked if version is the issue none found.

Below is my fragment for reference:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:me="sap.me" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Popover class="sapUiContentPadding" showHeader="false" placement="Auto">
        <List items="{staffXMLErrors>/}">
            <NotificationListItem title="{staffXMLErrors>Message}"
            tooltip="{i18n>overview.words.click_a_message_to_navigate}"
            showCloseButton="false"
            priority="{path:'staffXMLErrors>Type',formatter:'._Formatters.formatNotificationPriority'}"
            press="onStaffXMLErrorMessagePress" />
        </List>
    </Popover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: What is inside {staffXMLErrors>Message} ? if this is not a string, this is an issue :) [maybe you stored a sap.m.Text instance there ? thats my understanding of your error message]

Comment: That's just a string, how ever yesterday I tried below code in debugger console, and it still gives me error.

var abc = new sap.m.NotificationListItem({"titile:"xyz"});
Also below is giving error:
var ttt = new sap.m.MessageStrip({text:"abc"}); 

It looks some required library is not being loaded? as the above code works fine in a different fiori App from the same sap server.

Thanks,

Comment: var abc = new sap.m.NotificationListItem({title:"xyz"});
var ttt = new sap.m.MessageStrip({text:"abc"});

Answer (score 0):

As found out, the developer is loading all ui5 components explicitly in component.js like "sap.m.Text", "sap.m.label" ,"sap.m.NotificationListItem" etc., also there were several utilities included, as a trail I commented out all these and it worked fine.

so finally after removing all unwanted libraries, it worked fine.
At this point we could only avoid the issue but couldn't figure out what's exactly the reason is.